# A good reference for Javascript built-in objects?

Tags: javascript

Where can I find a good list and description of Javascript built-in objects?

I know there are things like Date, `Array`, `String`, `window`, `Number`, `RegExp` etc, but I can't find what methods they have anywhere. Is there a single authoritative place containing this information, like [php.net](http://php.net) does for for PHP?

Comment: Ahem... [the ECMAScript specification](http://es5.github.com/multi.html#x15-toc)? One would assume that the specification of a programming language defines the built-in object of that language...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find [Mozilla's MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) to be pretty comprehensive.

As for seeing what features are supported cross browser or not, [quirksmode](http://quirksmode.org/) is great. (Although I think there are other sources that are better for the newfangled html5 stuff)

Answer (score 4):

Have you seen [JavaScript Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference) on Mozilla Developer Network?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, the [ECMA specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)
(pdf), on which Javascript is based, is the official place to find that information.

`window`, incidentally, is technically *not* a built-in object, at least not by that name. It's known as the host object, which happens to be called window in web browsers, but is actually implementation-dependent.  The host object is where global variables are stored.

That's one of the neat things you find out when you * cough * [read the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) (pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I was googling for the same thing (equivalent to php.net for php) and found the following

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Predefined_functions

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/12k71sw7(v=vs.94).aspx